# Ways to check if all sublists have the same length/number of elements?

Tags: r, list, sublist

The main list can be dynamically created (i.e., the number of sublists may vary) so I cannot use all.equal or simply compare the lengths.

[In this attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54njY.png) for example, you can see that I have three sublists. How can I check if they have the same number of characters or list length(which in this case they do not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `lengths` and check if the number of distinct elements are equal to 1 or not

```
dplyr::n_distinct(lengths(main_list)) == 1
```

---

`n_distinct` will be just `length(unique(` in `base R`

```
length(unique(lengths(main_list))) == 1
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without packages? I haven't really acquainted myself with packages yet so I don't feel that comfortable using them at this stage.. just wanna start with very basic stuff. Anyhow, thanks for this answer!

Comment: @user200109 updated the post